# JavaScript Parent Node contains not working failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to change the icon image on click.

I add a class `active` to make the bottom div appear then i check if the `parentNode.contains("active")` i should have an image `else` i should have another image

but this method it doesn't work and i recive this message

> Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type
> 'Node'.

How can i fix this problem?

```js
let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.drop');
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.drop .inner-right img');

drops.forEach((drop) => {
    drop.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        drop.parentNode.classList.toggle("active");
        imgs.forEach((img) => {
            img.src = `../images/new icons/${e.currentTarget.dataset.img}`;
            if(drop.parentNode.contains("active")){
            }else{
                img.src = `../images/${e.currentTarget.dataset.old}`;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.box.active .bottom {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.box .bottom {
opacity:0;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box desc">
                            <div class="top drop" data-img="wasf al khotwa-01.svg" data-old="description.png">
                                <div class="inner-right">
                                    <img src="images/description.png" alt="desc">
                                    <p>Title</p>
                                </div>
                                <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom">
                                <p>
Text
                                </p>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: can you add jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you perform contains method on a node and not on the classList of the element

If you want to check if node have a specific class you can use

```
drop.parentNode.classList.contains("active")
```

```js
let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.drop');
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.drop .inner-right img');

drops.forEach((drop) => {
  drop.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    drop.parentNode.classList.toggle("active");
    imgs.forEach((img) => {
      img.src = `../images/new icons/${e.currentTarget.dataset.img}`;
      if (drop.parentNode.classList.contains("active")) {
        console.log('win')
      } else {
        img.src = `../images/${e.currentTarget.dataset.old}`;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.box.active.bottom {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.box.bottom {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box desc">
  <div class="top drop" data-img="wasf al khotwa-01.svg" data-old="description.png">
    <div class="inner-right">
      <img src="images/description.png" alt="desc">
      <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>
      Text
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```